# How can I develop a dependency without having to re-install after every change?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a Maven project consisting of two parts: a library, and a demonstration application. I'd like to be able to add to the library project and have the changes be available immediately in the demonstration without having to reinstall the library

Comment: Your IDE of choice might be able to resolve the dependency from its Workspace (I know Eclipse + m2e can do this).

Comment: IntelliJ can do it too. As far as I know a proper IDE really is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this like a job for a multi-module build like the following:

```
root(pom.xml)
  +--- library
  !       +-- pom.xml
  +---- demo
          +-- pom.xml
```

This will solve two things. First during the development of the library you can see if the demo's are influenced in some way furthermore you can fix the problems within the demo file apart from that the whole tree should be put into a version control system (svn: trunk, git: master) to handle versions and changes on that.